# Why drilldown x-axis points not matching with corresponding bars?

Tags: highcharts

So, I am trying to have a drilldown in Highcharts, where x-axis type is `datetime` and for that, I am passing data in milliseconds. But, it been found that my x-axis values do not align with the corresponding bar, there is a slight mismatch.

Also, every month value is having first value as last month last date, whereas I'm not even having that value rather it starts with 1st of that corresponding month.

Following is the JSFiddle of the Highchart:

http://jsfiddle.net/gkumar77/epzh14ou/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamps provided are midnight in the timezone GMT+05:30.

[Highcharts defaults to UTC](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.useUTC):

> "for axis scaling, tickmark placement and time display" ... "that the
>   time displays equally regardless of the user agent's time zone
>   settings"

So in UTC each of the timestamps corresponds to the previous day at 6:30PM. This is why the placement is off and this is why every month's first value is the previous month's last date.

You could make this work in your timezone by setting `useUTC: false` in Highcharts but it won't display correctly in other timezones.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({ 
    time: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
```

Alternatively you could also adjust all of those timestamps so that they correspond to midnight UTC time.

Depending on your requirements you could import Moment.js and Moment Timezone and use [time.timezone](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.timezone) to set the chart to work in 'Asia/Kolkata' timezone ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/yLfea1td/)).

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    time: {
        timezone: 'Asia/Kolkata'
    }
});
```